# PHP flat array to nested ["a", "b", "c"] to ["a" =>["b"=>["c"]]]

Tags: php, arrays

As the title with the example says, I need a flat array to be nested by each following key being the previous value.

Example:

```
array("I", "need", "this", "to", "be", "nested");
// To:
array("I" => array("need" => array("this" => array("to" => array("be" => array("nested"))))))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's one that just alters the original array instead of creating a new variable using `array_walk`:

```
$a = ["I", "need", "this", "to", "be", "nested"];
array_walk(array_reverse($a), function ($v, $k) use (&$a) {
    $a = $k ? [$v => $a] : [$v];
});
```

If `$a` is empty, this should just leave it as empty.  However, it does assume that your input array has keys starting from 0.

Comment: This is perfect! While I didn't ask for an in-place change, this seems to be the most compact version, which I was really looking for.

Comment: @DeadManWalker, actually this is not the most compact version. Here is a spelling of the first function from [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30365085/2266855): `function mn($a) { return count($a) < 2 ? $a : [array_shift($a) => mn($a)]; }`. Also my function is more efficient.

Answer (score 23):

Here is a possible implementation:

```
<?php

function make_nested($array) {
    if (count($array) < 2)
        return $array;
    $key = array_shift($array);
    return array($key => make_nested($array));
}

print_r(make_nested(array("I", "need", "this", "to", "be", "nested")));
```

If you don't like recursion, here is an iterative version:

```
function make_nested($array) {
    if (!$array)
        return array();
    $result = array(array_pop($array));
    while ($array)
        $result = array(array_pop($array) => $result);
    return $result;
}
```

Answer (score 17):

Using [`array_reduce`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php):

```
$a = ["I", "need", "this", "to", "be", "nested"];

$result = array_reduce(array_reverse($a), function($prevArray, $key){
    return $prevArray ? [$key => $prevArray] : [$key];
}, null);
```

Note that we're using [`array_reverse`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reverse.php) because there isn't a left reduce.

Working example: **http://ideone.com/N61VtE**

Answer (score 4):

I would use a `for`-loop for this :)

```
$array = array("I", "need", "this", "to", "be", "nested");

$newArray[$array[count($array)-2]] = array_pop($array);

for($i = count($array) - 2; $i > -1; $i--) {
  $newArray[$array[$i]] = $newArray;
  unset($newArray[$array[$i+1]]);
}

print_r($newArray);
```

Answer (score 3):

[Run The Code](http://ideone.com/osifGu)

```
<?php

  // nested_array(array, start_index, length)
  function nested_array($arr, $i, $size)
  {
      if ($i == ($size-1))
      {
          return array($arr[$i] => array());
      }
      return array($arr[$i] => nested_array($arr,($i+1),$size));
  }

  print_r(nested_array(array("I", "need", "this", "to", "be", "nested"),0,6));

?>
```

Comment: The OP wanted their innermost array to look like `array("be" => array("nested"))`, your code returns `Array([be] => nested)`. I'd think an empty array would made more sense, by the way: `["be" => ["nested" => []]]`.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be working.

```
$a = array("I", "need", "this", "this", "to", "be", "nested");
$r = array($a[sizeof($a) - 1]);
for ($i=sizeof($a)-2; $i >= 0; $i--) { 
    $r = array($a[$i] => $r);
}
echo($ar == $r);
```